# Clase conexion BBDD en PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo un ejercicio en el que debo crear la clase Conexion y el enunciado dice lo siguiente:

1. Tiene como atributos privados los parámetros de la conexión a la BD.
2. Tienen un único método protegido que realiza la conexión y devuelve el manejador de la conexión o si hay error muestra un mensaje y finaliza el programa.

Tengo la clase conexion que creo que me devuelve la conexión pero a parte de que no estoy seguro no sé cómo probarla, porque la prueba rápida que hice, no funciona.

```
class conexion {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $userName = "root";
    private $dbName = "protectora_animales";
    private $clave = "";
    
    protected function conexion()
    {
        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbName; charset=utf8", $this->userName, $this->clave);
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Error: " . $ex ->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Siguiendo el enunciado, no le he creado ningún atributo/propiedad para guardar la conexión, ni constructor.

Comment: La prueba lo que se supone que hace es una consulta a la tabla adopcion, simplemente para ver si la clase conexion devuelve la conexion o no. Pero me da error de llamar a un metodo exec inexistente(que es verdad que dentro de la clase no existe), pero esque entonces nose como hacerlo o si esque la clase esta mal.

Comment: El "Problema" está en que por todos lados veo ejemplos de la clase conexion pero con diferentes metodos de instanciar y conectar etc, pero como lo tengo que hacer yo que es solo con ese metodo protegido, no encuentro ninguno

Comment: El constructor no puede tener el mismo nombre de la clase y siempre va a devolver un objeto con instancia de la clase, por lo que ese `return $conn;` no es útil. Deberías extender tu clase desde PDO o crear una propiedad para almacenar la conexión.

Comment: no, no tiene constructor es un unico metodo que devuelve la conexion para poder utilizarla en otras clases. En cuanto a lo del metodo exec ya lo cambié

Comment: @Pepe la sintaxis que tienes si era una forma de declarar un constructor en PHP antes, donde el nombre era el mismo que el de la clase, pero ya no es algo válido por eso el comentario del otro usuario

Comment: ya antes si se que era con el mismo nombre de la clase, pero eso cambio por __construct nose cuando la verdad, he retocado el codigo a lo que tengo ahora pero nose si eso realmente devuelve la conexion para luego utilizarlo en otras clases

Comment: El constructor si puede tener el mismo nombre de la clase, pero debe evitarse, por cuestiones de estandarización y que desde PHP8 ya está marcado como DEPRECATED y será removido en futuras builds. Ver [Old-Style Constructors](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.decon.php).

Comment: @aeportugal, gracias por la aclaración. Creo recordar que a partir de la versión 7 ya marcaba error, no me hagas mucho caso, mi única neurona activa suele confundirse. De cualquier forma, el enlace que proporcionaste es claro al mencionar: **Always use __construct() in new code.**

Comment: @Triby estas en lo correcto desde la versión 7 de PHP se marca como deprecated

Comment: ¿Cómo no funciona? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿has visto las clases/funciones estáticas?

Comment: No tiene sentido el enunciado, porque los métodos protegidos no están disponibles fuera de la clase, por lo que el constructor está descartado (debe ser de acceso público) y no habrá forma de ejecutar ese método. Más información en [el manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Pero si luego extiendes esa clase o hacer un require o un include esos metodos protegidos si tienes que tener acceso creo. Alvaro Montoro no se si funciona o no porque no se como probarla, en cuanto a codigo a mi me aprece que esta bien mas o menos

Answer (score 3):

No puedes devolver una conexión de PDO en el constructor, porque la función del constructor es instanciar la clase y devolver la propia instancia. En todo caso, podrías extender la clase de PDO o almacenar la conexión como propiedad.

La tercera opción, sin usar propiedades adicionales es que el constructor no haga nada y tengas un método para conectar y devolver la conexión.

Ten en cuenta que cambié el nombre de la clase para iniciar con mayúscula, es el formato recomendado y evita posibles problemas con nombres de métodos.

```
class Conexion {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $userName = "root";
    private $dbName = "protectora_animales";
    private $clave = "";

    // El constructor no puede tener el nombre de la clase
    public function __construct() {}
    public function conexion()
    {
        try{
            // Conectar y asignar a la propiedad
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbName; charset=utf8", $this->userName, $this->clave);
            // Devolver conexión a PDO
            return $conn;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Error: " . $ex ->getMessage());
        }
    }
}

// Instanciar clase y obtener conexión
$conn = new Conexion()->conexion();

$sql = "select * from adopcion";

// Usa -> en lugar de :: y el método es query, no exec
$res = $conn->query($sql);

if($res !== false)
{
    echo  "Ha funcionado";
} else {
    echo "No ha funcionado";
}
```

**Importante:** Realmente no le veo mucho sentido a una clase donde no puedes tener propiedades para almacenar la conexión activa y, por tanto, no te va a ser posible darle usos adicionales.

Comment: Si que he visto algunos ejemplos asi, pero esque en mi ejercicio no me deja crear mas propiedades, como la de conexion, simplemente esas privadas y crear el metodo para establecer y devolver la conexion

Comment: @Pepe, revisa la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: La cosa es que el enunciado de la clase Conexion dice lo siguiente: 1- Tiene como atributos privados los parámetros de la conexión a la BD.
2- Tienen un único método protegido que realiza la conexión y devuelve el manejador de la conexión o si hay error muestra un mensaje y finaliza el programa.
Entonces por eso yo no le he creado ningun atributo/propiedad para guardar la conexion, ni constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Como lo ha editado Alvaro Montoro es como deberia ser la clase, (algo parecido he acabado teniendo solo tuve que cambiar de sitio el return), y en cuanto a lo de los metodos protegidos luego otra clase hereda de esta y asi se puede utilizar. Mi unica duda es si al instanciar y hacer $conn = new Conexion()->conexion();  yo ya tengo la conexion ahi guardada